# LDAP Configuration with Synology DSM

Tags: authentication-authorization

We have Synology DSM (Disk Station Manager) Installed in our office, and my Drupal 7 site is hosted on it. I want to use Directory Users to use Drupal with same credentials using LDAP.

I installed the LDAP required modules, but I am still having trouble configuring and connecting.

Did anyone work with LDAP with Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully integrated Drupal with DSM using LDAP project: https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap

Basicall DSM is running OpenLDAP which is supported by the project. Be sure to enable php-ldap extension.

The ldap module distribution comes with a set of submodules that you enable to configure LDAP authentication and authorisation:

- ldap_servers - define LDAP server
- ldap_user - Sync users (User entity fields to LDAP attributes) with LDAP
- ldap_authentication - Allows user to authenticate with their LDAP username/password
- ldap_authorization - Give Drupal users roles based on LDAP group.

It also provides a comprehensive GUI to visually configure everything. Also integrates with 'devel' to debug.

HTH